# Wrap input to value text length using each

Tags: jquery

If you type in the first item's input, you see it expands and that it's width was determined by the length of the value.

How do I iterate this for every item where the input width matches each item's value width?

```js
$(".item").each(function() {
  $(".input--span").text($(".input--item").val());
  $(".input--item").width($(".input--span").width());

  $(".item").on("input", function() {
    $(".input--span").text($(".input--item").val());
    $(".input--item").width($(".input--span").width());
  });
});
```

```css
.input--item,
.input--span {
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.input--item {
  border: none;
  min-width: 10px;
}

.input--span {
  display: none;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="item">
  <span class="input--span"></span>
  <input class="input--item" type="text" name="name" value="Item 1 Long Text" autocomplete="off" />
</p>
<p class="item">
  <span class="input--span"></span>
  <input class="input--item" type="text" name="name" value="Item 2" autocomplete="off" />
</p>
<p class="item">
  <span class="input--span"></span>
  <input class="input--item" type="text" name="name" value="I3" autocomplete="off" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>**[1]**</sup> No need to use `.each()` because in this case the loop will repeat the `input` event by the number of `item` elements  .. *it's unseen* but if you `console.log` anything in the `input` event in `.each` it will be repeated

<sup>**[2]**</sup> While you use `input` event for input you can use `$(".item .input--item")` instead of just `$(".item")`

<sup>**[3]**</sup> To catch the previous span of the desired input you can use `.prev()` .. *There're more selectors for that but in this case `prev()` will be the easiest one*

<sup>**[4]**</sup> To run the code onload you can trigger the input event by use `.trigger('input')` *you can remove it and see the deference*

```js
$(".item .input--item").on("input", function() {
  $(this).prev(".input--span").text($(this).val());
  $(this).width($(this).prev(".input--span").width());
}).trigger('input');
```

```css
.input--item,
.input--span {
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.input--item {
  border: none;
  min-width: 10px;
}

.input--span {
  display: none;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="item">
  <span class="input--span"></span>
  <input class="input--item" type="text" name="name" value="Item 1 Long Text" autocomplete="off" />
</p>
<p class="item">
  <span class="input--span"></span>
  <input class="input--item" type="text" name="name" value="Item 2" autocomplete="off" />
</p>
<p class="item">
  <span class="input--span"></span>
  <input class="input--item" type="text" name="name" value="I3" autocomplete="off" />
</p>
```